# Server-Client works with School Network, not with Home-Network

Tags: java, firewall, cmd.exe, anti-virus, client-server

I programmed a server client in java which work, but only with the network of my school. So when i have tried to test it with my home network it didn't work.
I have already checked the firewall configuration, but i didn't find any suitable setting to solve my problem.
Strangely i can ping my second pc with my main pc, but it doesn't work the other way.

I have already asked this question on stackoverflow, where they said it is network configuration problem.

Comment: Please provide more technical details as to what type of server-client it is, on what system they both are and what you have done till now by showing the commands or outputs.

Comment: Yes, we need to know more about the app - what ports are you using? Have you tried any other simple server on your main PC - maybe using Python or Node.JS and see if you can access anything. Also try changing the port number to something large, certainly >1024.

Comment: The server-client is written in java. It is a simple echo-server. They are both running on win10. I use ports greater equal than 5000. I found another strange thing. With every other PC i can't ping my second PC, but again the other way works.

Comment: Sorry, i am a bit late. The solution was pretty simple. I thought the problem was my main pc, but it was my second pc, which caused my problem. I had to go to the firewall settings of my second pc, where i noticed the firewall settings were not standard. They did not allow any  input. This how i solved it. I allowed tcp/ip and the current ip address of my main pc. I noticed it after i had used another pc to ping my main pc, which worked, and my second pc, which did not work.